# Xamarin splash screen only supports a single image

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, splash-screen

Is it really not possible to have rotating splash screen for Android and Ios?

For Ios i have a document of type

```
type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB"
```

which works fine but there doesn't appear to be a way to rotate this with random images.

For Android i have the following at the top of the SplashActivity class

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation=ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

What i am really trying to accomplish is to have a splash screen that is a rotation of about 6 images. So first time user opens app they would see first image and so on.

I can't imagine that people have not wanted splash screen to be dynamic. For example maybe on Halloween app would display pumpkin on splash etc.

Am i just missing something here?

Comment: "Dynamic Launch Screens" follow Apple "Human Interface Guidelines" and that includes that launch storyboards "...must not do any form of calculation or have any backing code..." This is by design to get your app started as quickly as possible and into a state of performing its given task, Apple calls this "**Downplay launch**" in their UI guidelines (if you want to read their point of view on the subject).  Of course you can insert your own storyboard that displays some rotating image from a selection that is segued after your app's launch screen and then you would segue to your main app UI.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes this is what i thought but just wanted some clarification. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you could create a animations for Splash screen. I use the jump for reference. You could create the .xml file according to what you want.

**Create a `Anim` folder and put the hyperspace_jump.xml file in it.**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.4"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.6"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="700" />
<set
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="700">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.4"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.6"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

**Create the layouts:**

SplashScreen Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   p1:minWidth="25px"
   p1:minHeight="25px"
   p1:layout_width="match_parent"
   p1:layout_height="match_parent"
   p1:background="@android:color/white"
   p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

   <ImageView
       p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
       p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
       p1:id="@+id/imageView"
       p1:layout_centerVertical="true"
       p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       p1:src="@drawable/a01" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

MainLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
android:text="Main Activity Started"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code Behind:**

SplashScreenActivity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
ImageView imageView;
Animation view_animation;
TextView textview;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
    imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);
    
    view_animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.hyperspace_jump);
     
    imageView.StartAnimation(view_animation);
    view_animation.AnimationEnd += Rotate_AnimationEnd;
    
}

private void Rotate_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
{
    Finish();
    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome to MainActivity", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

You could download from the GitHub for reference. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/SplashScreenDemo

**Updated:**

**Create a new activity to judge the day of week.**

Activity1.cs: Remove the `MainLauncher = true` from the `SplashScreenActivity`.

```
 [Activity(Label = "SplashScreenDemo", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        var dateTime = DateTime.Today;
        if (dateTime.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(ThursdayActivity));
        }
        else if (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(SplashScreenActivity));
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new splash screen layout `ThursdayLayout` with different image in ImageView and create a new activity for this named `ThursdayActivity`.

After that you could run the ThursdayActivity with Thursday splash screen when it is Thursday.

Comment: Thank you for great answer but what i meant by rotation was that for example on Monday the Monday splash screen shows and same for Tuesday etc.

Comment: What does the `example on Monday the Monday splash screen shows and same for Tuesday etc` mean?

Comment: It means that if you opened the app on monday you would see a different splash screen than if you opened it on tuesday. Also different on wednesday. In other words code would be if date.today==monday show mondaysplash etc

Comment: I would keep on searching and feedback ASAP.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i am looking for except the problem is this only works for Android. There doesn't appear to be a solution for IOS

Comment: The logic for ios is similar to android. ios could not use the animation for splash screen directly. You need to create the view for animation first. If you have questions for this, provide your code with errors.

Comment: Apple does not allow any coding for splash screen. It is a static file that is loaded when app starts up. See the comment from Sushi Hangover underneath my question which has a link to where apple talks about why this can't be done. Also i don't care about animation

Comment: @Maxqueue Yes, that's right. If using the `LaunchScreen.Storyboard`, it's a static file and can not be coded. If want to achieve a animation, we will use code to do. However, that will be not realted to the `LaunchScreen.Storyboard`.

Comment: I have stated several times i don't care about animation. Just want different screen to load based on some simple logic. Does Ios have an alternative to using storyboard?

Comment: @Maxqueue Sorry, launch storyboard can not do something according to different screen. because it not contains the property with screen size for us to call, and we also can not use code for launch stroryboard.